# How to specify ansible host as another docker container

Tags: docker, ansible

I have a VSCode dev container where I am authoring my ansible as I learn it (it is Ubuntu) and I have a Ubi8/ubi (RHEL 8) container running to be the host that the ansible gets run against.

I have added both to a new docker bridge network but I am unable to use the container name in the inventory yaml file to specify the rhel box

Comment: Does the host that you are trying to use Ansible to manage have an SSH server installed and running? Ansible needs that.

Comment: @NickODell that's not totally true, the connection of Ansible is indeed SSH per default but it also have a [`community.docker.docker`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_connection.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-connection) and a [`community.docker.docker_api`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_connection.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-connection) connections that can be used.

Comment: ^-- further reading: the [`community.docker.docker_containers`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_containers_inventory.html) dynamic inventory